# How to add an outline border to a table in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, formatting

I am trying to add only a border outline to a table in Google Docs however when trying to make all lines except the border lines another colour, this happens:

[image]

As you can see, white spots where the row and column lines end, also, I had to manually 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click all of them which can be a pain with a big table.

Is there any way to add a border to a table without having to all of this manually?

Comment: No, I want a full border around the whole table without having to select every individual row and column's line to make them black manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- select the table

  [image: 0]
- click the arrow/triangle and select a selection you need to highlight

  [image: 0]
- set the border parameters

  [image: 0]
- to avoid dots on border select insides of the table and set border width to **0pt**

  [image: 0]

Comment: That still gives the white dots where the row and column lines start and end.

Comment: @Tom answer updated

Comment: @Tom https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers